# Question about fouerier series (is this a typo?)

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

In a book that I am reading it says:

We can write the fourier series  (1) $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n
 e^{inx}$ as a partial sum

(2) $s_N(x)=\sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_n e^{-inx}$

Now in the partial sum the sign in the exponent has changed. Is this a typo or did I miss something.

Comment: In $(2)$, $s_N$ is clumsy written. Observe that $\sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_n e^{-inx}=\sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_n e^{inx}.$

Comment: @Fred I get it for the exponential term but why should $c_n = c_{-n}$

Comment: OOps . I have overlooked the coefficient $c_n$. $s_N$ in $(2)$ is false !